# Format button inside grid.column

Tags: button, grid

I'm going crazy with a problem involving the formatting buttons within a grid.
I'm working with Visual Studio 2015 with Xamarin (last updated).

I cannot define and centralize the buttons. They are larger than the columns and lose content when you do not fit in width.

My code is:

```html
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <Button BackgroundColor="Red" Text="Login" />
    <ScrollView Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Frame BackgroundColor="#ffc0ff"
                   OutlineColor="#000000"
                   Padding="2,2,2,2">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Button Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            BorderColor="Black"
                            BorderRadius="10"
                            Text="1"
                            TextColor="Black" />
                    <Button Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            BorderColor="Black"
                            BorderRadius="10"
                            Text="2"
                            TextColor="Black" />
                    <Button Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="2"
                            BorderColor="Black"
                            BorderRadius="10"
                            Text="3"
                            TextColor="Black" />
                    <Button Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="3"
                            BorderColor="Black"
                            BorderRadius="10"
                            Text="4"
                            TextColor="Black" />
                    <Button Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="4"
                            BorderColor="Black"
                            BorderRadius="10"
                            Text="5"
                            TextColor="Black" />
                    <Button Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="5"
                            BorderColor="Black"
                            BorderRadius="10"
                            Text="6"
                            TextColor="Black" />
                </Grid>
            </Frame>

            <Frame BackgroundColor="#ffc0ff"
                   OutlineColor="#000000"
                   Padding="2,2,2,2">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Button Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            BorderColor="Black"
                            BorderRadius="10"
                            Text="1"
                            TextColor="Black" />
                    <Button Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            BorderColor="Black"
                            BorderRadius="10"
                            Text="2"
                            TextColor="Black" />
                    <Button Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="2"
                            BorderColor="Black"
                            BorderRadius="10"
                            Text="3"
                            TextColor="Black" />
                    <Button Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="3"
                            BorderColor="Black"
                            BorderRadius="10"
                            Text="4"
                            TextColor="Black" />
                    <Button Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="4"
                            BorderColor="Black"
                            BorderRadius="10"
                            Text="5"
                            TextColor="Black" />
                    <Button Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="5"
                            BorderColor="Black"
                            BorderRadius="10"
                            Text="6"
                            TextColor="Black" />
                </Grid>
            </Frame>

            <Frame BackgroundColor="#ffc0ff"
                   OutlineColor="#000000"
                   Padding="2,2,2,2">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Button Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            BorderColor="Black"
                            BorderRadius="10"
                            Text="1"
                            TextColor="Black" />
                    <Button Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            BorderColor="Black"
                            BorderRadius="10"
                            Text="2"
                            TextColor="Black" />
                    <Button Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="2"
                            BorderColor="Black"
                            BorderRadius="10"
                            Text="3"
                            TextColor="Black" />
                    <Button Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="3"
                            BorderColor="Black"
                            BorderRadius="10"
                            Text="4"
                            TextColor="Black" />
                    <Button Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="4"
                            BorderColor="Black"
                            BorderRadius="10"
                            Text="5"
                            TextColor="Black" />
                    <Button Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="5"
                            BorderColor="Black"
                            BorderRadius="10"
                            Text="6"
                            TextColor="Black" />
                </Grid>
            </Frame>

            <Frame BackgroundColor="#ffc0ff"
                   OutlineColor="#000000"
                   Padding="2,2,2,2">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Button Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            BorderColor="Black"
                            BorderRadius="10"
                            Text="1"
                            TextColor="Black" />
                    <Button Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            BorderColor="Black"
                            BorderRadius="10"
                            Text="2"
                            TextColor="Black" />
                    <Button Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="2"
                            BorderColor="Black"
                            BorderRadius="10"
                            Text="3"
                            TextColor="Black" />
                    <Button Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="3"
                            BorderColor="Black"
                            BorderRadius="10"
                            Text="4"
                            TextColor="Black" />
                    <Button Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="4"
                            BorderColor="Black"
                            BorderRadius="10"
                            Text="5"
                            TextColor="Black" />
                    <Button Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="5"
                            BorderColor="Black"
                            BorderRadius="10"
                            Text="6"
                            TextColor="Black" />
                </Grid>
            </Frame>

            <Frame BackgroundColor="#ffc0ff"
                   OutlineColor="#000000"
                   Padding="2,2,2,2">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Button Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            BorderColor="Black"
                            BorderRadius="10"
                            Text="1"
                            TextColor="Black" />
                    <Button Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            BorderColor="Black"
                            BorderRadius="10"
                            Text="2"
                            TextColor="Black" />
                    <Button Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="2"
                            BorderColor="Black"
                            BorderRadius="10"
                            Text="3"
                            TextColor="Black" />
                    <Button Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="3"
                            BorderColor="Black"
                            BorderRadius="10"
                            Text="4"
                            TextColor="Black" />
                    <Button Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="4"
                            BorderColor="Black"
                            BorderRadius="10"
                            Text="5"
                            TextColor="Black" />
                    <Button Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="5"
                            BorderColor="Black"
                            BorderRadius="10"
                            Text="6"
                            TextColor="Black" />
                </Grid>
            </Frame>

            <Frame BackgroundColor="#ffc0ff"
                   OutlineColor="#000000"
                   Padding="2,2,2,2">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Button Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            BorderColor="Black"
                            BorderRadius="10"
                            Text="1"
                            TextColor="Black" />
                    <Button Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            BorderColor="Black"
                            BorderRadius="10"
                            Text="2"
                            TextColor="Black" />
                    <Button Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="2"
                            BorderColor="Black"
                            BorderRadius="10"
                            Text="3"
                            TextColor="Black" />
                    <Button Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="3"
                            BorderColor="Black"
                            BorderRadius="10"
                            Text="4"
                            TextColor="Black" />
                    <Button Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="4"
                            BorderColor="Black"
                            BorderRadius="10"
                            Text="5"
                            TextColor="Black" />
                    <Button Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="5"
                            BorderColor="Black"
                            BorderRadius="10"
                            Text="6"
                            TextColor="Black" />
                </Grid>
            </Frame>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <Button BackgroundColor="Green" Text="Login" />
</StackLayout>
```

This is what it looks like:

[image: This is what it looks like]

Comment: I improved the prose a bit and embedded the image for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need add VerticalOptions and HorizontalOptions  for button. Example:

```
 <Button Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        BorderColor="Black"
                        BorderRadius="10"
                        Text="1"
                        TextColor="Black" 
                        VerticalOptions = FillAndExpand,
                        HorizontalOptions = FillAndExpand />
```

Also try remove BorderRadius.

It is my example create buttons 5x5 in grid(in code):

```
    void CreateButtons(Grid _root)
    {
        int position = 0;
        int Size =5;
        int[] _filedNumber = new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };
        for (int row = 0; row < Size; row++)
        {

            for (int column = 0; column < Size; column++)
            {

                Button bt = new Button
                {
                     Text = (emptyText) ? string.Empty : _titleArr[position],
                     FontSize = _fontSize,
                     BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
                     VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                     HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                     bt.Caption = row
                };

                Grid.SetColumn(bt, _filedNumber[column]);
                Grid.SetRow(bt, _filedNumber[row]);
                _root.Children.Add(bt);
                position++;
            }
        }
    }
```

It is my grid in xaml:

```
  <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel"
          Grid.Row="1"
          Padding="10">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <OnPlatform x:Key="dividerThickness"
                            Android="1"
                            WinPhone="1"
                            iOS="1"
                            x:TypeArguments="GridLength" />

                <Style TargetType="BoxView">
                    <Setter Property="Color" Value="Accent" />
                </Style>

            </ResourceDictionary>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="{StaticResource dividerThickness}" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="{StaticResource dividerThickness}" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="{StaticResource dividerThickness}" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="{StaticResource dividerThickness}" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="{StaticResource dividerThickness}" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="{StaticResource dividerThickness}" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="{StaticResource dividerThickness}" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="{StaticResource dividerThickness}" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="{StaticResource dividerThickness}" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="{StaticResource dividerThickness}" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="{StaticResource dividerThickness}" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="{StaticResource dividerThickness}" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


        <BoxView Grid.Row="0"
                 Grid.Column="0"
                 Grid.ColumnSpan="11" />

        <BoxView Grid.Row="0"
                 Grid.RowSpan="11"
                 Grid.Column="0" />
        <BoxView Grid.Row="0"
                 Grid.RowSpan="11"
                 Grid.Column="2" />
        <BoxView Grid.Row="0"
                 Grid.RowSpan="11"
                 Grid.Column="4" />
        <BoxView Grid.Row="0"
                 Grid.RowSpan="11"
                 Grid.Column="6" />
        <BoxView Grid.Row="0"
                 Grid.RowSpan="11"
                 Grid.Column="8" />
        <BoxView Grid.Row="0"
                 Grid.RowSpan="11"
                 Grid.Column="10" />
        <BoxView Grid.Row="2"
                 Grid.Column="0"
                 Grid.ColumnSpan="11" />
        <BoxView Grid.Row="4"
                 Grid.Column="0"
                 Grid.ColumnSpan="11" />
        <BoxView Grid.Row="6"
                 Grid.Column="0"
                 Grid.ColumnSpan="11" />
        <BoxView Grid.Row="8"
                 Grid.Column="0"
                 Grid.ColumnSpan="11" />
        <BoxView Grid.Row="10"
                 Grid.Column="0"
                 Grid.ColumnSpan="11" />

    </Grid>
```

I had to spend time, but it works for me. Hope this help.